# Read object within array in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, object

I am trying to get the `_id` from the objects within an array.

```
[ { _id: 5ba49c6304daff5034e6fa6a,
    email: 'editor@gmail.com',
    active: true,
    events: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    name: { first: 'editor', last: 'editor' } } ]
```

Each object within events array contains a _id. I need to get those ids in another array.

```
if (userobj.events) {
   if (userobj.events[0]) {
         var eIds = [];
         for (var i = 0; i<userobj.events.length; i++) {
             console.log(userobj.events._id);
             eIds.push(userobj.events._id);
         }
             andArr.push({"_id":{"$in":eIds}});
      }
  }
```

I am getting `undefined` for each _id.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you meant this: `userobj.events[i]._id`.

Comment: Does your `events` property objects contain `_id` property? If it contains just use `for (var i = 0; i < userobj.events.length; i++) { console.log(userobj.events[i]._id); }`

Comment: @roryrjb Working. So stupid I am. Thank you so much.

Comment: @IsabekTashiev It does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
userobj ={ 
  _id: '5ba',
  email: 'editor@gmail.com',
  active: true,
  events: [ {_id:23},{_id:34},{_id:56},{}],
}

let listOfId = [];
userobj.events.map(({_id})=> { if(_id) listOfId.push(_id) });
console.log("listOfId",listOfId);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the [i] after **events** and before **._id** in for loop.

```
userobj.events[i]._id
```

This is whole your code in one line:

```
let eIds = userobj.events.map(ele=>ele._id)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to improve your solution. First, you are checking for null. Then you are pushing ids to the array. Here you can use some JS tricks and arrow functions like this;

```
let obj = { events: [ {_id: 1}, {_id: 2}, {_id: 3}] };

let eventIds = (obj.events || []).map(event => event._id);

console.log(eventIds);
```

Also, you can use ES6 destructuring as Muhammad shows;

```
let eventIds = (obj.events || []).map(({_id}) => _id);
```

Btw you can use reduce like this.

```
let eventIds = (obj.events || []).reduce((acc, elem) => {
    if(elem._id) {
       acc.push(elem._id);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```