# How to put values from an array of objects into a new array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects:

```
const array = [
  {id: 35, id_city: 27, id_district: 453},
  {id: 36, id_city: 27, id_district: 454}
];
```

I expect to get the "id_district" values into a new array so the result should be:

```
const ArraydDistrict = [453,454];
```

I guess the answer is simple, I am just really new at this so any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: yes.I now map @Bergi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read object within array in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447215/read-object-within-array-in-nodejs)

Comment: @MohammedAshfaq Thanks, it really help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array.map` to return the values.

```
const array = [
               {id: 35, id_city: 27, id_district: 453},
               {id: 36, id_city: 27, id_district: 454},
              ];

const result = array.map(el => {  return el.id_district})

//Results in [453, 454]
```

You could also use an implicit return to reduce verbosity.

```
const result = array.map(el => el.id_district)
```

If you want to be fancy, `ES6` lets you do this

```
const result = Array.from(array, el => el.id_district)
```

Comment: You can also omit the `idx` parameter to reduce verbosity…

Comment: @Bergi Yeah thanks, just a bad habit I got into because I often use the index :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a use case for Array.map

```
const arr = [{id: 35, id_city: 27, id_district: 453},{id: 36, id_city: 27, id_district: 454}];

const processedArr = arr.map(o => o.id_district);
console.info(processedArr);
```

Take a look at Array.map, Array.filter, Array.reduce all these functions come pretty handily in array processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution to put values from an array of objects into a new array in JavaScript:

```
const ArraydDistrict = [];
const array = [
    {id: 35, id_city: 27, id_district: 453},
    {id: 36, id_city: 27, id_district: 454},
];

array.forEach(function(item) {
  ArraydDistrict.push(item.id_district);
});

console.log(ArraydDistrict);
```

Comment: @MikeM also known as "reinventing the wheel"